# How to add Googles utm_source variable in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-analytics, utm

I am using a permalink structure in wordpress like `www.domain.com/sample-post/` but it blocks naturally all parameters which it doesnt know.

I actually just want to add Googles `?utm_source=` variable to some links to track some sources, but Wordpress blocks them and i get a 404 error with a `/none` output in my logs.

Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: How do you have your permalink structure defined in wp-admin? Can you post your `.htaccess` rewrites?

Answer (score 2):

instead of using ? you can elect to use # to pass utm_source values.

to do this just add this line to analytics tracking code above _trackPageview
      _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);

Now you can tag utm_source parameters like this
http://mysite.net/index.html#utm_source=Source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Name

As data after # isnt passed to servers wp would continue to see the same url

Answer (score 1):

```
# Block the include-only files. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L] 

# Preventing Directory Listing, Leads to Block and 403 and 401
Options -Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

hi,

i am using domain.com/sample-post/ as permalink structure